# Repeat watcher.go:208] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted

Tags: kubectl, kubernetes-helm, rancher, etcd

I use Rancher HA AirGap. After I run docker command I get result of etcd!?

```
docker run -v backup:/backup -p 8080:80 -e CATTLE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT_REGISTRY="172.18.3.9:5000" 172.18.3.9:5000/rancher/rancher:v2.1.5

Result: 2019-02-05 13:37:11.457132 I | 
mvcc: store.index: compact 13988 2019-02-05 13:37:11.462784 I | 
mvcc: finished scheduled compaction at 13988 (took 2.639034ms) 2019-02-05 13:42:11.466068 I | 
mvcc: store.index: compact 14319 2019-02-05 13:42:11.472226 I | 
mvcc: finished scheduled compaction at 14319 (took 3.076376ms) 
E0205 13:46:27.432964 7 watcher.go:208] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted

^C2019-02-05 13:47:05.124730 N | pkg/osutil: received interrupt signal, shutting down... 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Received SIGTERM, cancelling 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down ClusterController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down ClusterRegistrationTokenController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down ProjectRoleTemplateBindingController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down SourceCodeRepositoryController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down RoleBindingController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05
 [INFO] Shutting down PipelineExecutionController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down PipelineController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down SecretController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down SecretController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down SettingController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down SourceCodeCredentialController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [ERROR] kube-controller-manager exited with error: interrupted 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down AuthConfigController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down ClusterRoleController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down ListenConfigController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down ClusterRoleBindingController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down RoleController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down NodePoolController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down RoleTemplateController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down UserAttributeController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down GlobalRoleController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down TokenController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down ClusterRoleTemplateBindingController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down GlobalRoleBindingController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down UserController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down DynamicSchemaController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down NodeController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down ProjectController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down GroupController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [INFO] Shutting down GroupMemberController controller 2019/02/05 13:47:05 
 [FATAL] context canceled
```

Cluster Config Rancher:

```
nodes:
  - address: 172.18.3.15 # hostname or IP to access nodes
    user: ubuntu1604rone # root user (usually 'root')
    role: [controlplane,etcd,worker] # K8s roles for node
    ssh_key_path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa # path to PEM file
  - address: 172.18.3.16
    user: ubuntu1604rtwo
    role: [controlplane,etcd,worker]
    ssh_key_path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa

addons: |-
  ---
  kind: Namespace
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: cattle-system
  ---
  kind: ServiceAccount
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: cattle-admin
    namespace: cattle-system
  ---
  kind: ClusterRoleBinding
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: cattle-crb
    namespace: cattle-system
  subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: cattle-admin
    namespace: cattle-system
  roleRef:
    kind: ClusterRole
    name: cluster-admin
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    name: cattle-keys-ingress
    namespace: cattle-system
  type: Opaque
  data:
    username: dWJ1bnR1MTYwNHJ6ZXJv
    password: dGVzdDEyMyMh
  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    namespace: cattle-system
    name: cattle-service
    labels:
      app: cattle
  spec:
    ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
      name: https
    selector:
      app: cattle
  ---
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    namespace: cattle-system
    name: cattle-ingress-http
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "30"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"   # Max time in seconds for ws to remain shell window open
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"   # Max time in seconds for ws to remain shell window open
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: cloud.nikafarinegan.com  # FQDN to access cattle server
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: cattle-service
            servicePort: 80
    tls:
    - secretName: cattle-keys-ingress
      hosts:
      - cloud.nikafarinegan.com      # FQDN to access cattle server
  ---
  kind: Deployment
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  metadata:
    namespace: cattle-system
    name: cattle
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: cattle
      spec:
        serviceAccountName: cattle-admin
        containers:
        - image: 172.18.3.9:5000/rancher/rancher
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: cattle-server
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 443
            protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Can you provide your etcd version ?